# Usage of the ur- prefix

Tags: formality, prefix, spoken-language, informal

From what I understand 'ur-' is used, roughly:

- to refer to origin, as in 'Urgroßmutter'
- to strengthen an adjective or adverb, as in 'urschön' (~very beautiful) or 'urplötzlich' (~very quickly)

I've only heard it in very casual/relaxed contexts so far (e.g. 'urschön'), but I'm wondering whether it should always be confined to informal conversations. If not, are there any ur- words which are safe to use in more formal settings?

Edit: Following comments I should say I currently live in Vienna.

Comment: I've never heared "urschön" before. German [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ur-) says the prefix "Ur-" refers to a very old thing which is long ago and primarily ("ursprünglich"). There are some examples, too: Urahn, Urwald, Urzeit, Urkunde, Ursprung or uralt, urgermanisch, uramerikanisch, ureigen.

Comment: The prefix 'ur-' is used extensively in [Viennese colloquial language](http://www.echtwien.at/home/literatur/lexikon/U/852) as Elativ for adjectives. I am not sure though, if it is used elsewhere in this way.

Comment: And to confuse even more: "Urlaub", which just *looks like* using the same prefix.

Comment: @tofro: Yeah, a very good comment. What a pitty I cannot give +10 to your comment. See https://www.dwds.de/wb/Urlaub for more information on "Urlaub"

Comment: @IQV It might be regional, I live in Vienna

Comment: @kof That sounds like it, thanks for the link!

Comment: @tofro Gibt es Urlaub im Urwald?

Comment: @CarstenS [ur|un]wahrscheinlich

Comment: ...and to follow @tofro's idea: "urbar" is not an old pub, (although it would possibly be a cool name...) but in the context "urbar machen" means cultivating an acre/a field.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms *urbar* actually **is** the same prefix IMHO - you could say "ich mache Land bar [frei] von Urwald"

Comment: @tofro - nice. Just looked into this, this has some nice examples: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?lemid=GU13604

Comment: There are two prefixes Ur-, one meaning "ancient" or "original", the other being the nominal prefix related to the verbal prefix er-. "Urkunde", "Urlaub" and "Ursprung" derive from the latter, that is they are related to "erkennen", "erlauben" and "erspringen". "urbar" comes from a word for yield which is made of "er-" and "-bären", which meant _to bear_, but is only used in "gebären", _to give birth_, anymore. Source: Kluges Etymologisches Wörterbuch.

Comment: @sgf Nadaschja wirklich klug.

Comment: @Casten S Heinz Erhardt: Urlaub im Urwald
Ich geh' im Urwald für mich hin...
Wie schön, daß ich im Urwald bin:
man kann hier noch so lange wandern,
ein Urbaum steht neben dem andern.
Und an den Bäumen, Blatt für Blatt,
hängt Urlaub. Schön, daß man ihn hat!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only adjectives you want to prefix with ur- in formal conversation are "uralt" and "urplötzlich". Using "ur" to intensify other adjectives as in "urschön" is Viennese youth language. (And really only used in Vienna and Lower Austria.)

Comment: That's the anwser I was looking for. Can I ask where you are based?

Comment: Around the Viennese area - obviously, or I wouldn't even know that that is a thing :) I would be very surprised if people outside of Austria knew the ur- prefix for intensifying, and it marks you clearly as a Viennese everywhere in the western parts.

Answer (score 7):

## The answer

See https://www.dwds.de/wb/ur- which is very helpful, especially when you have a look on the etymology. You are right in stating that *ur-* is used to refer to the origin of something far back:

> 1. bezeichnet den Anfang, das erste, etw. sehr weit Zurückliegendes"

Examples are

- Urbevölkerung
- Urwald
- Urmensch

other examples, but with interesting semantic nuances (when you take care of the literal meaning of the nouns used in the composita) are

- Ursache (*cause*)
- Ursprung (*origin*)

**The second meaning**

> 2. bezeichnet Echtheit, Unverbrauchtheit, den idealen Zustand nach der Entstehung, Produktion von etw.

*genuineness, authenticity* is raising from the first. To my eye the most interesting example here is

- Urtext

which combines the semantics of *authenticity* and *origin*:

> An urtext edition of a work of classical music is a printed version intended to reproduce the original intention of the composer as exactly as possible, without any added or changed material."
>   (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urtext_edition)

Notabene that the english *genuine* (with the etymology of latin *gignere* "beget" - see https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genuine) - also relies on the semantic connection of *origin* and *pureness*, *authenticity* Also take notice that *origin* has strong etymological links to *ur-*, see https://www.dwds.de/wb/original - the *or-* in *origin* correlates to *ur-*.

**The third meaning**

> bezeichnet einen hohen Grad

*a high degree* is the explanation for your examples

- urplötzlich (Caution: you wrote "ur**s**plötzlich, which is wrong) and
- urschön (which I have never heard before, to me it sounds like some regionalism)

## Additional information

### Youth language

In youth language there exists (or at least: existed, when I was youth) the superlative *urst* which is used to denote a very high degree of something ("urst schön", "urst langweilig"). I think that the grammatical interesting construction of a "superlative" of a prefix (which does not exist in standard german!) is a typical means of youth language to demonstrate deviance of the norms of the adults.

### Related concepts in german language

Caution, the following is somewhat speculative and must be read cum grano salis:

In german language there is a semantic connection between concepts of *authenticity*, *pureness* and *origin*. As a very prominent example for the first take the title and concept of Immanuel Kant's "Kritik der Reinen Vernunft" where "rein" ("pure") means "unvermischt" (*unmixed*) but also *clean*, *neat*)
Ideas which are blending concepts of *pureness*, *origin* and *authenticity* are raising especially in german Romanticism (consider for instance "Die Christenheit oder Europa" by Novalis), but have german predecessors - take, for example, Martin Luther with his concentration on the bible as the pure origin of Christianity. (But this is very associative and maybe loses the track of your question.)

That's why I was not surprised when I learned that english language uses a germanism to denote *Urtext*.